# cell states of LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

Could you tell me why state of LSTM cells are updated after every batch process in a validation and a test?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L269

I suppose that state of LSTM cells should be same value in a validation and a test.

Answer (score 0):

No. The states have to be updated. This is connected with how the data fed to the network. One sentence is spanning multiple batches. E.g. say we have batch_size = 1 and num_steps = 2 then you'd have for a sentence "the brown fox jumps" first a batch b1 = ['the', 'brown'] and then another batch b2 = ['fox', 'jumps']. What tensor flow simply does is to take the final hidden state that it got as result of processing b1 and re-uses it as initial state for b2 which makes perfect sense right?

In other words, this is completely independent of whether you are training, testing or running on the validation set. Further, updating the state also has nothing to do with changing the parameters of the model.

Answer (score 0):

The initialized value of cell_state are set by you, normally we use zero state to initialize.

Yet once you start an rnn process, the state is updated according to the input sequence. You can regard the state as "how the rnn network understand the sequence". So when the network is fed with different sequences, the cell states are different.